# Converse of Principal Ideal Theorem

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, dimension-theory

$(A, \mathfrak{m})$ a Noetherian local ring, $a\in\mathfrak{m}$ a *zero divisor*. Then is it true that $\mbox{dim}\ A/(a) = \mbox{dim}\ A$ ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. Let A be the ring k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz) localized at (x,y,z).  Then the dimension of A is 2, but the dimension of A/(x) is one.  Note that xz = 0 in A.

The geometric picture is this: In 3-space, take the union of the horizontal z=0 plane with the vertical line x = y = 0, and look at the local ring at the origin.  Then restricting to x=0, we get the union of the y-axis and the z-axis.

Comment: Such pictures are good for the memory.

Comment: @Charles Staats: What is the most easiest way to see that dimA=2? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Necessary and sufficient conditions for your question to have a positive answer are that $A$ be $\textit{unmixed}$, that is, every associated prime is a minimal prime, and $\textit{equidimensional}$, that is, $\mathrm{dim} (A/\mathfrak{p}) = \mathrm{dim}(A)$ for every minimal prime $\mathfrak p$.  Charles Staats' example is not equidimensional.  The one-dimensional ring $A=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ is not unmixed, and $A/(y)$ has dimension zero.  Sufficiency follows from the fact that the set of zerodivisors of $A$ is equal to the union of the associated primes.